# Updating column values according to a specific combination of duplicates in R

Tags: r

I am still new to R and I am attempting to solve a seemingly simple problem. I would like to identify all of the unique combinations of values from 4 different rows, and update an additional column in my df to annotate whether or not it is unique.

Giving a df with columns A-Z, I have used the following code to identify unique combinations of column A,B,C,D, and E. I am trying to update column F with this information.

```
unique(df[ ,c("A", "B","C","D", "E")])
```

This returns each of the individual rows with unique combinations as expected, but I cannot figure out what the next step I should take in order to update column "F" with a value to indicate that it is a unique row. Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: can you please show your expected output

Comment: Try `df$F <- duplicated(df[, c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")])`

Comment: Be aware that `unique()` does not return elements or combinations that occur only once in your data, but rather omits the duplicated elements. Example: `unique(c(1, 2, 2))` returns `1 2`.